# bsoncxx::stdx::optional and mongocxx::stdx::optional

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost-optional

Is there any difference between `bsoncxx::stdx::optional` and `mongocxx::stdx::optional` in MongoDB C++ driver?
Do they both inherit `boost::optional`?

I can't find descriptions about them in the MongoDB C++ Driver API Documentation.

Comment: MongoDB C++ driver is an open source project (Link: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/). You can simply look into it to find that out. Here's the `optional.hpp` where these have been defined (Link:  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/bsoncxx/stdx/optional.hpp ).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! @Azeem

Comment: You are welcome! :)

Comment: They are the same: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/mongocxx/stdx.hpp#L24

Comment: Am I seeing that right?  Is `bsoncxx::stdx::optional` just an alias (in the general sense) of `std::optional` from the standard library?